# Can't concatenate a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, string, string-concatenation

I am trying to make a calculator with javascript. My code below takes the button clicks and adds them all together as a string. When the user presses the sum or equals button, the function is supposed to evaluate the string as an equation and log a result. for example result == "2 * 10" should return 20. My problem is that instead of doing that it just adds it together rather than multiplying or doing any other function like - or divide.

here is my code:

```
var result = 0;

function calc(digit){

   if (digit == "sum"){
       console.log(eval(result)) ;
   }
   else if (digit == "-"){
       result + "-";
   }
   else if (digit == "+"){
       result + "+";
   }
   else if (digit == "*"){
       result + "*";
   }
   else if (digit == "/"){
       result + "/";
   }
   else if (digit == "."){
       result + ".";
   }
   else if (digit == "clear"){
       location.reload();
   }
   else{
       result += parseFloat(digit);
   }

}
```

and here is an example of a button click for each function:

```
<button class="large" type="button" value="divide"onclick=calc("/")>/</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use assignment operators for this.

For example, instead of `result + "-"`, use `result += "-"`. You had the right idea in your else block.

Anyways, since your code has multiple `if/else` conditionals, it would be better to use a `switch` statement

```
function calc(digit){
   switch(digit) {
       case: "sum":
           console.log(eval(result));
           break;
       case "-":
           result += "-";
           break;
       case "+":
           result += "+";
           break;
       case: "*":
           result += "*";
           break;
       case: "/":
           result += "/";
           break;
       case: ".":
           result += ".";
           break;
       case "clear":
           location.reload();
           break;
       default:
           result += parseFloat(digit); 
    }   
}
```

Here's some more information on String Concatenation in JavaScript

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp

Comment: Hahah! Silly me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In your if stack, `result + "-"` doesn't do anything. To add the minus sign to the end of result, you would do something such as

```
result  = result + "-";
```

or

```
result += "-";
```

Currently, `result + "-"` has the system do the concatenation of result and the string, but immediately loses it because you didn't store it back in result.